# Button onClick inside DataTables doesn't show the correct url

Tags: datatables

I'm displaying all the customer data using DataTables like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var theTable = null;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        theTable = $('#table-customer').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "ordering": true, 
            "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]], 
            "ajax":
            {
                "url": "http://localhost/myshop/showdata.php", 
                "type": "GET"
            },
            "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
            "deferRender": true,
            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, 50],[ 5, 10, 20, 50]], 
            "columns": [
                { data: "cust_id" }, 
                { data: "cust_name" }, 
                { data: "cust_addr" },
                { data: "cust_email" },
                { data: "cust_phone" },
                { data: "cust_photo", sortable: true, render: function (o) { return '<button id="btn1" onclick="displayImage(data)">Show</button>';}
            ]
        });
    });

    function displayImage(link){
      window.alert(link);
    }

    </script>
```

All information is displayed properly, except 1 thing: if you click any button on "customer photo" column, instead of showing an alert which shows its URL, nothing happens. Inspecting the page showed me this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (view.html:1)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The `columns.data` render function builds a string which is returned:

```
function (o) { return 'your string here, including data value'; }
```

You have to (a) concatenate your data variable with the string literals you need; and (b) use the variable name you provided - I will use `data` instead of `o`:

```
function (data) { return 'your string here, including ' + data + ' value'; }
```

So, if we provide all the possible parameters allowed in the renderer, that becomes:

```
{ 
  "data": "cust_photo", 
  "sortable": true, 
  "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<button id="btn1" onclick="displayImage(\'' + data + '\')">Show</button>';
  }
}
```

I use `\'` to ensure the value of the `data` variable is surrounded in single quotes.

(**Note** that in your question, the code is also missing a closing `}`.)

But to avoid potential issues with sorting and filtering, these column data render functions need to account for DataTable's use of [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).

The `type` parameter can be used for this:

```
{ 
  "data": "cust_photo", 
  "sortable": true, 
  "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
    if (type === 'display') {
      return '<button id="btn1" onclick="displayImage(\'' + data + '\')">Show</button>';
    } else {
      return data; // type is for sorting or filtering - just use the raw value
    }
  }
}
```